# Sublime Vintage navigation with +,- not working?

Tags: sublime-text-3

So +, - keys are supposed to navigate to the next/prev line starting on the first non-white space character.

But it doesn't do anything when I tried.

Is it not supported?

Don't think I have any key bindings overridding it either.